# How we can create RemoveBlack Image Filtering same like RemoveWhite in FabricJs?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

how we can remove black pixels from image? Can we create RemoveBlack Image filtering same like RemoveWhite?

Comment: Did my answer below help?  Do you need anything else?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going:

[image: fabricjs image filters custom]

Here's the relevant code for a custom filter:

```
fabric.Image.filters.RemoveBlack = fabric.util.createClass({
  type: 'RemoveBlack',
  applyTo: function(canvasEl) {
    var context = canvasEl.getContext('2d');
    var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvasEl.width, canvasEl.height),
      data32 = new Uint32Array(imageData.data.buffer), // create a uint32 buffer
      i = 0,
      len = data32.length;
    while (i < len) {
      if (data32[i] < 0xff300000) data32[i] = 0; // if close to black, set transparent
      i++
    }
    context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  }
});
fabric.Image.filters.RemoveBlack.fromObject = function(object) {
  return new fabric.Image.filters.RemoveBlack(object);
};
```

And here's the all important JSFiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/rekrah/pf072kxs/.

Let me know if you have any questions.  Happy to help further.

Comment: Looks like this is no longer working with most recent version - I get the error canvasEl.getContext is not a function